# How to store session id and parameter values in Dialogflow per session?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have built a bot that adds elements, deletes them, checks if present and more.

I want to store all the inputs from the user along with his session id to further analyse it and identify him next time he will come.

Please advise how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with AWS Lex and AWD DynamoDB. Basically Lex had a session timeout of 1-2 days but I wanted it longer than that. So I persisted the session values in DynamoDB (you can use any NoSQL table) using the userId as hash key and timestamp as sort key. So every time the session changes, I save the entry in DB.

Regarding reading, I checked if session data is available. If so, use that, otherwise fetch last entry from DB.

Comment: Please instruct me, if for example item1 parameter equals 55, how can I further access this value and pass it to webhook and python backend?

Comment: what exactly is item1? a slot filled by the user? If so you can add a webhook for slot filling https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook In your webhook you have access to noSql db and also your items and sessionId. Just do a save/put

Comment: webhook will have the URL to your rest server or to your google function